# html2canvas not rendering emojis with modifiers properly

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji, html2canvas

Html2canvas can't render elements which contain emojis with modfiers such as skin color. For example:  turns into: [image] in Firefox.

Code example:

HTML:

```
<div id="target">&#128105;&#127999;</div>
<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

JS:

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLw7ozya/1/

Anyone know of a way to fix this? Or will I just have to find a way to remove all the modifiers before rendering?

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://github.com/nprapps/lunchbox/issues/35), this is something that is currently in the works to be developed.

The accepted solution there is:

> FYI the latest beta version of html2canvas supports emoji. I've just tested using https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/tag/v0.5.0-beta4 and it seems to work.

Comment: I am afraid I am already using the beta in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: Whelp, unfortunately, this is only something that can be resolved from the `html2canvas` team. Try using the 1.0 alpha?

Comment: Cheers FrankerZ, that atleast works a bit better than the other alpha. Aalhough still not perfect. For example it fails to render ‍♂️